# Emacs magit diff-buffer scrolling - how to stop at bottom

Tags: scroll, emacs, magit

Wondering if anyone knows the parameters that control scrolling in magit. Currently, when I'm in the *magit-log* buffer and keep hitting the space key, the diff view in the other window scrolls to the bottom, and continues back to the top and scrolls - effectively endlessly. Is there a way to make it stop at the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option for that, but you can get the behavior you want be redefining `magit-diff-show-or-scroll-up`:

```
(defun magit-diff-show-or-scroll-up ()
  "Update the commit or diff buffer for the thing at point.

Either show the commit or stash at point in the appropriate
buffer, or if that buffer is already being displayed in the
current frame and contains information about that commit or
stash, then instead scroll the buffer up.  If there is no
commit or stash at point, then prompt for a commit."
  (interactive)
  (magit-diff-show-or-scroll (lambda () (scroll-up))))
```

Comment: Nice.. I'm guessing you're forcing the `(pcase ..` to not match and make the scroll a no-op on error. thanks - it works!